# Migrating from redis to mongodb in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, redis

I am completely new to Mongodb. Earlier I have used redis to store the data that I have processed in my ruby on rails application. My redis content is like following:

```
 students_<roll_num>: {marks_obtained:..,major_subject:...,..etc.}
```

Here above `students_<roll_num>` is the hash where roll_num varies, i.e.  number of hashes depends on the number of students in the class. I have already put in redis after converting its value to a JSON object. But due to some issues I have to put all those above info in mongodb. I have never used mongo before, so I have no idea how to do this. So if anyone helps me with any idea about this I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your data stored in redis and insert the data in mongodb's collection in following manner :
Create a document like :
j = {students_ = {marks_obtained:..,major_subject:...,..etc.}}

and then insert the same using :

db.student.insert( j )

Where student is the name of collection where you can keep the data in mongodb.

For further reference you can checkout the [tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/) of mongodb